# When do I use “many” or “any” in a question?

Tags: word-choice, determiners

Which of the two questions is correct?

> Are there many shelves in the closets?
>
> Are there any shelves in the closets?

I don't understand the difference of using *any* or *many* in a question.

Comment: "Any" is more than zero. "Many" is more than a small number (more than *some*). If there was one shelf, the answers would be "No, just one" and "Yes, there is one" would be the answers to your questions, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there many shelves in the closets?

You know there is a nonzero number of shelves in the closets.  You're trying to find out if there is a small number or large number of shelves.

> Are there any shelves in the closets?

You don't even know if the closets have shelves or not.  You're trying to find out if there are zero shelves or a nonzero number of shelves.

Comment: *"You know there is a nonzero number of shelves in the closets."* I disagree that an *are there many* question necessarily implies that you know there are any. "Have there been many Christian presidents of India before?" "No, none at all." / "Did you get many bug bites on your hike?" "No, I lucked out -- the bugs spared me!"

Comment: Guess I should have said "know or believe" rather than just plain "know."

Comment: I still think that might be a bit stronger than the real use of *are there many*. Sometimes, you are intentionally clumping none and few together, asking whether something is normal, typical, unremarkable or whether it would be a fluke (which has or has not happened before).

Comment: Someone might say *many* when they don't want to say *any* to be nice, polite, politically correct, or inclusive.  In your examples there is a context of politeness/deference, in which oftentimes the literal meaning of certain phrases is intentionally not meant.  This phenomenon has a wider span than just the two words *any* vs. *many* (e.g. modals are often "wrongly" used for politeness).

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict replies to Yes and No, they're asking two different things. For 'many', a No answer may mean that there are few shelves or no shelves. 'Many' is in the eye of the beholder. For 'any', a Yes answer doesn't tell if there are many shelves, just that there's at least one

Allowing non-binary answers, they can be essentially the same question. If one asks about either 'many' or 'any', the answer can supply a quantity. For example "Are there many?" "No, there are none". vs. "Are there any?" "Yes, there are four". Both tell you what you (probably) want to know.